# App deployment failed, invalid pointer Windows 8 phone SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, sdk

I am using windows phone sdk 8 and visual studio 2012 in windows 8 pro. When i run my application it give this error that application deployment failed and emulator gets shut down. What is solution for that please tell me. Thanks

Comment: It happened to me sometimes too, it's about getting the environment going on. Check your Hyper V settings. My problem was actually my antivirus which was interferring (I had AVG). See if any of these work out for you as well.

Comment: It is solved now thanks :) i had network problem.

Answer (score 1):

1- Press (HOME+W) and search for "turn windows features on or off"

2- deactivate the hyperV of ur system

3- apply and ur system will restart

4- activate hyperV again